# How to bind an array of json objects to an array of javascript class in ES6

Tags: javascript, json, class, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a single page application that connected to a restful web service on Reactjs my problem is not related to Reactjs it's just about a design pattern that should implemented correctly on Javascript.

in a part of project i send a GET request to server and take back a Json response that contains information about addresses.
Above there is complete response of my request :

```
{
  "Result": "Done",
  "Errors": null,
  "Model": {
    "UserAddresses": [{
      "AddressId": 121,
      "AddressName": "",
      "AreaId": 1
    }, {
      "AddressId": 122,
      "AddressName": "",
      "AreaId": 1
    }, {
      "AddressId": 123,
      "AddressName": "",
      "AreaId": 1
    }, {
      "AddressId": 124,
      "AddressName": "",
      "AreaId": 1
    }],
    "AvailableAreas": [{
      "AreaId": 1,
      "AreaName": "داخل شهر",
      "Cost": 0
    }, {
      "AreaId": 2,
      "AreaName": "شهرک عباس آباد",
      "Cost": 5000
    }, {
      "AreaId": 3,
      "AreaName": "ویرمونی",
      "Cost": null
    }, {
      "AreaId": 6,
      "AreaName": "راه آهن",
      "Cost": null
    }]
  }
}
```

As you can see there are two arrays in json above **UserAddresses** and **AvalibleAddresses** so what do i want to do is i want to bind this to arrays to their own classes i implemented a class name Address that includes both of these to array :

```
export default class Address {

  constructor(avalibleAreas, userAddresses) {

    this._avalibleAreas = avalibleAreas;
    this._userAddresses = userAddresses;
  }

  get avalibleAddresses() {
    return this._avalibleAreas;
  }

  set avalibleAddresses(avalibleAreas) {
    this._avalibleAreas = avalibleAreas;
  }

  get userAddresses() {
    return this._userAddresses;
  }

  set userAddresses(userAddresses) {
    this._userAddresses = userAddresses;
  }
}
```

So after getting response i used that class in my controller like this:

```
let address = new Address(responseAsjson.Model.AvailableAreas,responseAsjson.Model.UserAddresses)

console.log(address)
```

And as you can see i passed that two arrays as params to constructor then the result of **console.log(address)** is:

```
Address {_avalibleAreas: Array(4), _userAddresses: Array(4)}
_avalibleAreas: Array(4)
0: {AreaId: 1, AreaName: "داخل شهر", Cost: 0}
1: {AreaId: 2, AreaName: "شهرک عباس آباد", Cost: 5000}
2: {AreaId: 3, AreaName: "ویرمونی", Cost: null}
3: {AreaId: 6, AreaName: "راه آهن", Cost: null}

_userAddresses: Array(4)
0: {AddressId: 121, AddressName: "", AreaId: 1}
1: {AddressId: 122, AddressName: "", AreaId: 1}
2: {AddressId: 123, AddressName: "", AreaId: 1}
3: {AddressId: 124, AddressName: "", AreaId: 1}
```

Now the problem is i want to have **UserAddresses** and **AvalibleAreas** in specific classes but i dont know how i can do this and for example have AreaId AreaName and Cost as property of the AvalibleAreas Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by "in specific classes", but you could create two additional classes like this:

```
class UserAddress {
  constructor(addressId, addressName, areaId) {
    this._addressId = addressId;
    this._addressName = addressName;
    this._areaId = areaId;
  }

  // place your getters and setters here
}

class AvailableArea {
  constructor(areaId, areaName, cost) {
    this._areaId = areaId;
    this._areaName = areaName;
    this._cost = cost;
  }

  // place your getters and setters here
}
```

And then you replace your old constructor in the `Address` class by this one:

```
constructor(availableAreas, userAddresses) {
  let a = [];
  let b = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < availableAreas.length; i++) {
    a.push(new AvailableArea(availableAreas[i].AreaId, availableAreas[i].AreaName, availableAreas[i].Cost));
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < userAddresses.length; i++) {
    b.push(new UserAddress(userAddresses[i].AddressId, userAddresses[i].AddressName, userAddresses[i].AreaId));
  }

  this._availableAreas = a;
  this._userAddresses = b;
}
```

Also: not related to the question, but <s>avalible</s> is meant to be *availible*, I think. That might save you some debugging time.

Comment: Thank you it was absolutely clear. in order to being more obvious i going to ask another question.is it common to do something like this in Javascript project? i mean separating models and views in this way or like traditional way combine ui codes and models together? I`m confused because there is no a clear MVVM design patterns for Javascript framework such as react.

Comment: @ravaei I think it's perfectly fine if you use this method. The only drawback I can think of, is that it's a little bit slower: you need to fill the 2 arrays in the `Address` constructor. 
However, programming like this makes your code more readable: if you spread out your code among multiple classes, it makes it more understandable (also to others who might look into your code). 
Here it's just with 3 classes, so you could understand the code pretty easily if you just left it in one. However, when you keep expanding your code like that, it might end up like "spaghetti", an unorganized mess.